# How to make intellij idea to complete insertion by enter?

Tags: intellij-idea

When i'm ready to use autocomplete i press enter but instead of getting the completed word the  new line is added. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed as 'not a real question'. I have the exact same problem after messing up my IntelliJ setup and I'm wondering just that: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See below for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use up/down arrows to select completion variant or set this option to `Always`:

[image: completion]

Comment: i logged in just to upvote this. I literally looked all the shortcuts thinking it was keymap :) would of never thought of this! Ty!!

Comment: This setting is no longer there in IntelliJ 2016.1. Do you know where they moved it?

Answer (score 3):

Yikes, the problem was that i misconfigured keymap. The `enter` key works by default.

Comment: In case others wonder what may be a possible misconfiguration: check that your keymap has "Editor Actions -> Enter" and "Editor Actions -> Choose Lookup Item" mapped to the Enter key.